# Onenote Api calls return internal server error 500

Tags: php, api, graph, request, onenote

we have developed a web app for add students in class notebooks for an academy. I recently noticed  the API is returning a 500 error when we make a call:

```
"error": {
"code": "10001",
"message": "An unexpected server error has occurred. Please try again later."
```

And this is our POST call:

```
https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/myorganization/siteCollections/{site collection id}/sites/{site id}/notes/classNotebooks/{notebook id}/Students
```

Site id and notebook id changes depending of the SharePoint Team Site.

We have not applied any change recenlty in this function and was working fine...

Can someone help me? it's a problem of the service?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This was an incident on our side and has been since resolved - please let us know if you are still seeing this. In the future, feel free to open a ticket to us here: https://aka.ms/edusupport